# __declspec(dllimport) works in .vcxproj but not in CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, cmake

Trying to convert a .vcxproj to CMake, I am unable to get `__declspec(dllimport)` to be picked up.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)

project(imgui.NET.Native VERSION 1.88)

set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED true)

# imgui

add_library(imgui SHARED
    imgui/imgui/imgui.cpp
    imgui/imgui/imgui_draw.cpp
    imgui/imgui/imgui_demo.cpp
    imgui/imgui/imgui_widgets.cpp
    imgui/imgui/imgui_tables.cpp
)

target_compile_definitions(imgui
    PUBLIC 
        IMGUI_DISABLE_OBSOLETE_FUNCTIONS 
        IMGUI_DISABLE_OBSOLETE_KEYIO
)

if (WIN32)
    target_compile_definitions(imgui 
        PUBLIC 
            IMGUI_API=__declspec\(dllexport\)
    )
else()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Not implemented")
endif()

# implot

add_library(implot SHARED
    implot/implot/implot.cpp
    implot/implot/implot_demo.cpp
    implot/implot/implot_items.cpp
)

target_include_directories(implot PUBLIC imgui/imgui)

target_compile_definitions(implot 
    PUBLIC 
        IMGUI_DISABLE_OBSOLETE_FUNCTIONS 
        IMGUI_DISABLE_OBSOLETE_KEYIO
        IMPLOT_DISABLE_OBSOLETE_FUNCTIONS
)

target_link_libraries(implot imgui)

if (WIN32)
    target_compile_definitions(implot
        PUBLIC 
            IMGUI_API=__declspec\(dllimport\)
            IMPLOT_API=__declspec\(dllexport\)
    )
else()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Not implemented")
endif()
```

When I compare the preprocessor definitions in the manually crafted .vcxproj and the one generated by CMake, they both do have `IMGUI_API=__declspec(dllimport)` for implot library.

However, I am still getting [LNK2001](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk2001?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(LNK2001)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=msvc-170) when building the project generated by CMake.

It is when I added that line in the original .vcxproj that I fixed these LNK2001 errors.

Any ideas?

Comment: Adding the dllexport define `PUBLIC`ly doesn't look right. I'd expect something like `target_compile_definitions(implot PRIVATE IMGUI_API=__declspec\(dllexport\) INTERFACE IMGUI_API=__declspec\(dllimport\))`, but I'd rather use a header with defines that default to `dllimport`, if a specific preprocessor symbol isn't defined; CMake provides functionality for generating such a header: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/GenerateExportHeader.html

Comment: I tried to apply PRIVATE as you suggested but the project wouldn't still build up. I then realized that I installed the original CMake and added it as a path to all users. I uninstalled it and used Visual Studio's own and it worked immediately . Thanks for pointing me out in the right direction.